# Check if the device supports scrolling wallpapers programmatically

Tags: android, scrollview, android-wallpaper

Some launchers do not support scrolling wallpapers. Is there a way to check this programmatically? I've checked WallpaperManager and I cannot find a reference to this. Thanks